# Image transition with keyframes

Tags: css, transition, css-animations

Hey guys I am currently building an image show (small) with css3 keyframes, and it is working, but only on firefox in some way, and I cant seem to tackle the problem :( It should work in the latest versions of chrome firefox and safari, but its currently only working in firefox.

Anyone can that can help?

Here's the css that should work in al above browsers.

```
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

.case-image {
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
  width:32%;
}
.case-image img {
  position:absolute;
  width:                100%;
  height:               auto;
  left:0;
 border:                            3px solid #f8d206;
    -moz-border-radius:                 15px;
    border-radius:                      15px;
    margin-left:                        -3px;
    margin-right:                       -3px;

}

.case-image img {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

  -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;

  -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 8s;

  animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
.case-image img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.case-image img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.case-image img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.case-image img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are writing out your transition properties the long way?

Comment: Are you using the @-webkit-keyframes prefix as well somewhere?

Comment: No i've built this with a tutorial, not much of coding hero, if i understand it right -o- -mox- -webkit- are for the different browsers?

Comment: In the css validator it also states the following:   rule 405 .case-image img:nth-of-type(4)  0 is not a animation-delay value : 0

Comment: Yep :) so the same way you're specifying and repeating code for the animations e.g. -moz-animation-name... -webkit-animation-name... you need to do it for the @keyframes. So it does add up to a lot of repeating code, but it's necessary to function in the browsers that currently support it.

Comment: Can you go in a little more detail? what do i have to add where?

Comment: Sure. Here's a lame looking example, but you can see in the CSS pane I'm repeating the keyframes with the different vendor prefixes http://jsfiddle.net/tjfogarty/Gzxkq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the vendor prefixes for the keyframes. See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tjfogarty/Gzxkq/

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
    100% { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
    100% { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
    100% { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
}
```

Etc...

You can also use something like this: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ to take care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is so much clearer! Much appreciated!

Comment: The unprefixed keyframes should always be last. (Also, Firefox 16+ supports unprefixed keyframes.)